# Generate a libsvm formatted data from text file

Tags: matlab, weka, libsvm

Firstly, i'm very poor in data pre-processing. I was looking for WebKB data in libsvm format. Later after searching a lot over the internet, i came across this data obtained after stemming and stop-word removal. The format is as follows,
Each line represents a vector and the first word in each file contains the class name followed by some list of words which forms the feature delimited by spaces.
How do i convert such a text file to lib-svm format? Is there any Weka or Matlab tool to construct it?

Comment: Seems you missed the link to the data. You need to provide more details in your question.

Comment: @iTech [Link to WebKB dataset](http://web.ist.utl.pt/~acardoso/datasets/). Now, looks like I have to preprocess the entire original dataset myself [original dataset](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/~webkb/). Is there any tutorial or softwares which I can use to convert the original dataset to lib-svm format?

Answer (score 0):

libshorttext1.1 is a python module having utilities for this purpose with so many extra features. try it, or i think  scikit learn packages also have this functionality